# Exception: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message while using embed in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, embed

```
@bot.command()
async def who(ctx):
  r1=random.choice(MostLikely)
  embed=discord.Embed(title=r1, color=0xC964F0)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def nhie(ctx):
  r2=random.choice(Nhie)
  embed=discord.Embed(title=r2, color=0xC964F0)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def truth(ctx):
  r3=random.choice(Truth)
  embed=discord.Embed(title=r3, color=0xC964F0)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def dare(ctx):
  r4=random.choice(Dare)
  embed=discord.Embed(title=r4, color=0xC964F0)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Code was working fine in discord, the bot responded to the commands when I used it earlier but then whenever I do it now, it gives me an error, even though I have not touched the code since.**

```
Ignoring exception in command truth:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 1254, in truth
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1089, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 262, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 977, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 870, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 101, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

[the same code working just fine earlier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfJkt.png)

Comment: What are the values of the variables you passed to `random.choice`? If those return `None` or empty string, the title will be empty and so this error occurs.

Comment: @puncher those are lists with the suitable questions, example 
Truth = ["When was the last time you cried?", 
  "What's your biggest fear?",
 "What's your biggest fantasy?"] it was working just fine earlier, i don't know what's going on this time

Comment: @puncher just an additional note, whenever I use the help command, that doesn't really use random.choice at all, it still gives me that error

Comment: Are this list hardcoded or do you grab it from somewhere?

Comment: they are hardcoded

Comment: okay, print `embed` to see what it returns. I guess it's `None` which is strange

Comment: <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x7f9530780310>

Comment: mhh. Then try reinstall discord.py

Comment: okay i reinstalled it and it worked tysm!